# Octobercms, redirect to home from component not working

Tags: redirect, components, octobercms

i'm trying to redirect from component if id from slug is wrong.

Running from layout

```
function onBeforePageStart(){ $this->Contentloader->getMeta(); }
```

In component i have:

```
public function getMeta(){

//id checking logic goes here

if ($id == null) return Redirect::to('/'); }
```

Inspecting the dd(Redirect::to('/')) object I see

[image]

But it's not redirecting.

Please advice

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

in your component :

```
public function getMeta()
{
   if ($id == null) return false;
}
```

in your layout :

```
function onBeforePageStart()
{ 
     $meta = $this->Contentloader->getMeta();
     if(!$meta)
          return Redirect::to('/');

}
```

I hope help you :)

Comment: But I also want to know why I cannot use redirect from component?!

Comment: function onBeforePageStart(){ return $this->Contentloader->getMeta(); } -- if you added `return` there then it should work, you missed that. redirect must return from `onBeforePageStart` to work so you need tor return it from there to

Answer (score 0):

Components should be able to handle redirects without having `onBeforePageStart()`. This is just a quick example. Here I am checking to see if a component field is null. If it is null then return to '/'.

You can do this in a component: Make sure to utilize the Redirect class `use Redirect;`

```
public function defineProperties()
{
    return [
        'useSomething' => [
            'title'             => 'Something',
            'description'       => 'Testing Testing',
            'default'           => '',
            'type'              => 'text',
        ]

    ];
}

public function onRun()
{

    if ($this->property('useSomething') == null) {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    } else {
        $this->page['something'] = $this->property('useSomething');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried onRun() before this and onInit() .... nothing. 
Page of redirection is rendered (you can see the attahed photo) but it's not redirecting.

Comment: Well you do know that die and dump won't redirect the page but dump the object. It seems to be showing the target url is https://localhost/ which would be where you want the redirect to go to right?

Comment: @aleXela Do you have `dd(Redirect::to('/'))` inside the if statement??